# textwrap.fill provides odd results when printing from a class Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

While textwrap.fill works with manually entered text, i.e. print("(Really long string)"), it yields unexpected results when printing from a class that has been populated from a csv file.

for example:

```
print(item.name,":",(textwrap.fill(item.description))
```

I get the following:

```
 Hide Armor : This crude armor consists of thick furs and hides. It is commonly
worn
by barbarian tribes, evil humanoids, and other folk who lack access to
the tools and materials needed to create better armor.
```

Any ideas? There are no line breaks in the CSV already.

The line from the CSV reads:

```
Hide Armor,10,12 + Dex modifier (max 2),-,-,20 lb.,"This crude armor consists of thick furs and hides. It is commonly worn by barbarian tribes, evil humanoids, and other folk who lack access to the tools and materials needed to create better armor.",Medium
```

That's a single line.

Any ideas on removing the random line break? Could it be to do the random whitespace at the beginning of the output? I don't know where that whitespace is coming from and appears even when not using the textwrap module.

Comment: It looks like the first line is longer than your terminal width and your terminal (or windows console) is doing the wrapping.

Comment: I'm currently compiling and testing in geany. I am unable to change the width of the terminal in there to test, so I will try straight from Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your terminal or console is doing the wrapping; you have a prefix on the line that you need to take into account when wrapping. Include it in the text you are wrapping:

```
print(textwrap.fill('{}: {}'.format(item.name, item.description)))
```

I've used [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) here to create a new string from the `.name` and `.description` attributes, with a colon in between.